# Arduino Due Serial Port Not Showing - Mac

Tags: arduino-due

Using a Mac (Big Sur 11.1)

When trying to set up the IDE I was able to install the package that contained the Due board, but the serial port for my Arduino Due isn't appearing in Tools -> Port -> Serial Ports. I did some searching and it seems that other Mac users had this problem as well.

If anyone has any tips on how to get my computer to recognize and show the serial port I'd appreciate it. I'm just getting started with these.

Comment: If your Due has an FTDI transceiver on it I'm curious to see a picture of it.  The only Due clones that I've seen, like the original, use at ATMega16u2 for the transceiver chip, in which case the FTDI drivers play no role.

Comment: Yeah that was a misstep in my end. I was just trying different things until I learned that. Now I’m wondering if it’s an issue with the OS.

Comment: It is probably best to remove that from the question then, because it just creates a rabbit hole.

Comment: Do you have anything at all attached to the board besides the USB cable?

Comment: Good suggestion. I removed it and no only the USB

Comment: It's been a while since I had much contacts with macs, but there should be a "device manager" of some sort.  USB device will list in it even if there are no drivers, wrong, drivers, etc.  You can edit into your question information regarding whatever shows up in there, or if nothing shows up at all.  Make sure you're focused on the "programming" port, since that gives the greatest chance of success.